# How to not lose messages when publishing to RabbitMQ from Mule until the proper "Ack" is received?

Tags: rabbitmq, mule, amqp, jms-topic

I have a synchronized Mule flow which reads messages from a sonic topic and publish to a Rabbit exchange.

I am loosing messages when the Rabbit is brought up/down.
Rabbit exchange is publishing to HA queues.
How can I make sure Mule is not consuming the message until proper "Ack" is received from Rabbit Broker?
Here is the flow.

```
<jms:connector name="sonicMQConnectorSub" validateConnections="true" connectionFactory-ref="factorySub" doc:name="JMS" clientId="testClient" durable="true" maxRedelivery="-1" >
     <reconnect-forever frequency="30000"/>
</jms:connector>
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="soniqMQConnectionFactoryBeanSub" name="factorySub" class="progress.message.jclient.ConnectionFactory">
        <spring:property name="connectionURLs" value="tcp://server1:7800" />
        <spring:property name="defaultUser" value="user" />
        <spring:property name="defaultPassword" value="pass" />
    </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>

<amqp:connector name="AMQP" validateConnections="true" host="server2" fallbackAddresses="server3" doc:name="AMQP Connector" port="5672" mandatory="true" activeDeclarationsOnly="true">
    <reconnect-forever frequency="30000"/>
</amqp:connector>


<flow name="rabbitFlow1" doc:name="rabbitFlow1" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint doc:name="JMS" connector-ref="sonicMQConnectorSub" topic="testtopic"/>

    <logger message="Message: #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

    <amqp:outbound-endpoint exchangeName="rabbitExchange" exchangeDurable="true" responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="AMQP" doc:name="AMQP" exchangeType="fanout"/>
 </flow>
```

Updated 04/22

Here is the exception trace when Mule is connecting to the 2nd broker. This is when I loose a message.

```
2014-04-22 09:49:29,453 - org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy - ERROR -
********************************************************************************
Message               : Connection shutdown detected for: AMQP
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Software caused connection abort: recv failed (java.net.SocketException)
java.net.SocketInputStream:-2 (null)
2. connection error; reason: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection     abort: recv failed (com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException)
com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection:715 (null)
3. Connection shutdown detected for: AMQP (org.mule.transport.ConnectException)
org.mule.transport.amqp.AmqpConnector$1:502     (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/transport/ConnectException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
+ 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************

2014-04-22 09:49:29,453 - org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy - INFO -    Exception caught is a ConnectException, attempting to reconnect...
2014-04-22 09:49:29,454 - org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager - INFO - Stopping   connector: AMQP

2014-04-22 09:49:29,454 - org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager - INFO -   Stopping: 'AMQP.dispatcher.1064499250'. Object is: AmqpMessageDispatcher
2014-04-22 09:49:29,454 - org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager - INFO -  Disposing: 'AMQP.dispatcher.1064499250'. Object is: AmqpMessageDispatcher
2014-04-22 09:49:29,455 - org.mule.transport.amqp.AmqpConnector - ERROR - clean  connection shutdown; reason: Attempt to use closed connection
2014-04-22 09:49:29,461 - org.mule.transport.amqp.AmqpConnector - INFO - Connected:    AmqpConnector
{
name=AMQP
lifecycle=stop
this=33c5919e
numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
connected=true
supportedProtocols=[amqp]
serviceOverrides=<none>
}

2014-04-22 09:49:29,461 - org.mule.transport.amqp.AmqpConnector - INFO - Starting:   AmqpConnector
{
name=AMQP
lifecycle=stop
this=33c5919e
numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
connected=true
supportedProtocols=[amqp]
serviceOverrides=<none>
}

2014-04-22 09:49:29,461 - org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager - INFO - Starting  connector: AMQP
```

Updated 04/23 with the Exception received when JMS Transaction is added to AMQP outbound Endpoint:

```
Message               : No active AMQP transaction found for endpoint:      DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=amqp://rabbitExchange, connector=AmqpConnector
{
name=AMQP
lifecycle=start
this=25ec1ff7
numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
connected=true
supportedProtocols=[amqp]
serviceOverrides=<none>
}
,  name='endpoint.amqp.rabbitExchange', mep=ONE_WAY, properties={exchangeDurable=true,     exchangeType=fanout}, transactionConfig=Transaction   {factory=org.mule.transport.jms.JmsTransactionFactory@6491b172, action=ALWAYS_JOIN,   timeout=30000}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.transaction.IllegalTransactionStateException: No active AMQP transaction  found for endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=amqp://rabbitExchange,   connector=AmqpConnector
{
name=AMQP
lifecycle=start
this=25ec1ff7
numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
connected=true
supportedProtocols=[amqp]
serviceOverrides=<none>
}
,  name='endpoint.amqp.rabbitExchange', mep=ONE_WAY, properties= {exchangeDurable=true, exchangeType=fanout}, transactionConfig=Transaction {factory=org.mule.transport.jms.JmsTransactionFactory@6491b172, action=ALWAYS_JOIN,  timeout=30000}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started,   responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}
at org.mule.transport.amqp.AmqpMessageDispatcher.getEventChannel(AmqpMessageDispatcher.java:298)
at org.mule.transport.amqp.AmqpMessageDispatcher.doOutboundAction(AmqpMessageDispatcher.java:152)
at org.mule.transport.amqp.AmqpMessageDispatcher.doDispatch(AmqpMessageDispatcher.java:127)
+ 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************

2014-04-23 10:52:03,178 - org.mule.transport.jms.JmsTransaction - WARN - Transaction   rollback attempted, but no resource bound to   org.mule.transport.jms.JmsTransaction@d4ac3d8f-caf6-11e3-bf9a-8b266a026dee  [status=STATUS_MARKED_ROLLBACK, key=null, resource=null]
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two options:

- Make the JMS client a durable one and consume `testtopic` transactionally so if `amqp:outbound-endpoint` fails, the message will be redelivered.
- Wrap the `amqp:outbound-endpoint` with `until-successful` to retry the outbound dispatches until the AMQP connector reconnects to RabbitMQ.

Comment: 1. When I use "Until Successful", the flow starts consuming messages, I want messages to remain in sonic durable connection.

Comment: 2. JMS Client is already durable. Do you suggest a transaction as follows: <jms:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>. How can i include AMQP in the transaction?

Comment: You can't join an AMQP transaction to a JMS one so you can only join the local JMS transaction with `<jms:transaction action="ALWAYS_JOIN"/>` in `amqp:outbound-endpoint` : exceptions raised by the `amqp:outbound-endpoint` will fail the JMS transaction.

Comment: It says "Element: Transaction is not allowed to be child of element AMQP"

Comment: Strange. What version of the transport are you using?

Comment: AMQP - 3.4.1 and Mule 3.4.0

Comment: Added the exception stack occurs when 1 broker goes down. That is when I loose 1 message.

Comment: Outbound endpoints offer no guarantee of not losing any message: reliability comes from either the inbound endpoint redelivering messages via failed transactions or using until-successful. We need to make this work in your case.

Comment: I agree. but doesn't this have to do with AMQP transport acknowledging the message delivery, when it shouldn't?

Comment: The AMQP transport acknowledges messages from inbound endpoints. For outbound there's no acknowledgement that needs to be done. Or are you thinking of the "Confirms" RabbitMQ extension? If that's the case, this extension is not supported currently.

Comment: You you say: "It says "Element: Transaction is not allowed to be child of element AMQP"" What is "It"? Studio or Mule? Studio is known to give bogus XML validation errors.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about the confirms.

Comment: The Element Error is from Studio. When I deploy the app ignoring that, I get a different error. It is updated in the question above.

Comment: I would like to see whether there is a way to handle this issue by updating the amqp code. Any further info from your end is really appreciated. I added another question if you have a moment. Thank you very much for the help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23251456/how-to-build-mule-amqp-transport-code-with-eclipse-plugin