# How to build Mule AMQP transport code with Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, mule, amqp, transport

I would like to branch AMQP and try to update the code for a message loss issue I came across.
https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-transport-amqp

I already created a branch.
What maven commands can I use the build AMQP transport along with Eclipse plugin?
[i executed "mvn clean compile package" which produced the mule-transport-amqp-3.4.2-SNAPSHOT.jar, but it didn't create the file required for updating it in Eclipse]

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

- `cd amqp-eclipse-plugin`
- `mvn clean compile package`